# HTML GET reading XML

Tags: xml, vb.net, console-application

I am using the following code to get an XML data from a website of mine:

```
Dim strUrl As String = "http://www.xxx.net/mobileApp/checker.asp"
   Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(strUrl)

   Do While (reader.Read())
      Select Case reader.NodeType
         Case XmlNodeType.Text 'Display the text in each element.
              Console.WriteLine(reader.Value)
      End Select
   Loop
Console.ReadLine()
```

My XML file looks like this:

```
<mobileApp>
   <jobid>513220</jobid>
   <ncdid>02132265</ncdid>
   <ncddescript>blah blah and more blah</ncddescript>
</mobileApp>
```

Problem being is that, although it does show the text within the tags, i am looking to find the tags name and THEN get the text that’s associated with it instead of just relying on the data to always be in the same order all the time.

Example of what i am looking for:

> ```
> case tags
>    "jobid"
>        msgbox "jobid is " & tags.jobid.value
> etc....
> ```

Any help would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the XMLTextReader reads the file sequentially, the Element name will be displayed right before its value.  Keep track of it in a string variable and do your select case from that.

```
    Dim strElementName As String = String.Empty

    Do While (reader.Read())

        If reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element Then

            strElementName = reader.Name

        ElseIf reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Text Then

            Select Case strElementName

                Case "jobid"

                    'Do Work

            End Select

        End If

    Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If the XML file is going to have the same set of elements each time, you could look at using XPath to query the XML file for particular elements and then output the value of each one. Something like:

```
Dim strUrl As String = "http://www.xxx.net/mobileApp/checker.asp"
Dim XPathDoc As New XPathDocument(New XmlTextReader(strUrl))
Dim Nav As XPathNavigator = XPathDoc.CreateNavigator()

'Query for jobid element
Dim JobIDElem As XPathNodeIterator = Nav.SelectSingleNode("./mobileApp/jobid")
MsgBox("JobID is " & JobIDElem.Value)
```

To get a different element out just change the search string in `SelectSingleNode` to select the element you want.